# LINUX Load average

Tags: linux, debian, central-processing-unit

My server Load jump high up top 22, CPU just 50%, RAM 1858/5120. How to know what process couse so high load average. Linux Debian

Comment: Can you update your question with what diagnostics you've already done?  ps output?  iostat output?  actual top output?

Answer (score 5):

```
$ grep processor /proc/cpuinfo |wc -l
4
```

That gives you the number of CPUs on your system. If the load average is higher than this number, but CPU is just 50%, there are good chances that you system is performing a lot of IOs.
In which case:

```
aptitude install iotop
```

iotop will give you a list of processes consuming disk IOs.

Comment: I have cloud server CPU are 4 nad 50%, after I order 8 CPU use 8 % load average down in 1.5, but if order 7 CPU load average jump to 22 again... when I install iotop gives me error:File "/usr/bin/iotop", line 16, in <module>....

Answer (score 3):

> How to know what process couse so high load average.

You can use `top`, press <kbd>O</kbd> (o in uppercase), follow by <kbd>l</kbd> (CPU Time), and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

zombie process can influence load average too,
May I suggest  :

```
mike@mike-:~$ ps -eo state |uniq -c
    171 S
      1 R
      1 D
      2 S
```

--> here you can count the number of process for each state

D (process blocked waiting for a resource)

Z Zombie

--> typical issue for the D status a process using a file on a NFS share who doesnt answer anymore...
Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of those three commands. Read the `man` or `info` pages for more information.

> uptime - Tell how long the system has been running.
>
> w - Show who is logged on and what they are doing.
>
> top - display Linux processes

All three commands show you the `load average` information. `top` is probably the best choice as it displays information about CPU usage, memory usage, priority, etc.

I cite from a reference of a course:

> Load average is the average of the load number for a given period of
>   time. It takes into account processes that are:
>
> - Actively running on a CPU.
> - Considered runnable, but waiting for a CPU    to become available.
> - Sleeping: i.e., waiting for some kind of    resource (typically, I/O) to become available.

I cite further about **interpreting load average**:

> The load average is displayed using three different sets of numbers,
>   as shown in the following example:
>
> The last piece of information is the average load of the system.
>   Assuming our system is a single-CPU system, the 0.25 means that for
>   the past minute, on average, the system has been 25% utilized. 0.12 in
>   the next position means that over the past 5 minutes, on average, the
>   system has been 12% utilized; and 0.15 in the final position means
>   that over the past 15 minutes, on average, the system has been 15%
>   utilized. If we saw a value of 1.00 in the second position, that would
>   imply that the single-CPU system was 100% utilized, on average, over
>   the past 5 minutes; this is good if we want to fully use a system. A
>   value over 1.00 for a single-CPU system implies that the system was
>   over-utilized: there were more processes needing CPU than CPU was
>   available.
>
> If we had more than one CPU, say a quad-CPU system, we would divide
>   the load average numbers by the number of CPUs. In this case, for
>   example, seeing a 1 minute load average of 4.00 implies that the
>   system as a whole was 100% (4.00/4) utilized during the last minute.
>
> Short term increases are usually not a problem. A high peak you see is
>   likely a burst of activity, not a new level. For example, at start up,
>   many processes start and then activity settles down. If a high peak is
>   seen in the 5 and 15 minute load averages, it would may be cause for
>   concern.